# GUI for the diction tool

Tags: gui, text-editor, latex, tools

I just stumbled upon the excellent ***diction*** tool. It's great to check the writing style of my LaTeX files, the problem is, however, I can only use it through the command line. The output, while being useful is very difficult to sift through. Is there a GUI for the ***diction*** tool? Even an editor or syntax highlighting support in the form of a text editor would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The only "GUI" for diction, I'm aware of is GNU Emacs. However Emacs is a fully-fledged editor which can do quite lots of things. You'll need a file called [diction.el](http://web.archive.org/web/20120302223746/http://www.burlingtontelecom.net/~ashawley/gnu/emacs/diction.el). Copy this to the subdirectory `.emacs.d` of your home directory. Now open a document in Emacs and type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> diction-buffer and press Enter. This will run the software on your currently opened file and provides a graphical user interface.